# Get Milliseconds and NanoSeconds in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to get Age, Months, Hours, Minutes, Seconds, MilliSeconds, NanoSeconds from DOB but I get an error when trying to get milliseconds or nanoseconds:

> Msg 535, Level 16, State 0, Line 3
>   The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff with a less precise datepart.

I was also try conversion method to solve but it can't - any ideas?

Code:

```
DECLARE @date datetime

SELECT @date = '2/11/1990 12:03:25.310 AM'

SELECT (DATEDIFF(yy, @date, GETDATE()) - CASE WHEN (MONTH(@date) > MONTH(GETDATE())) OR (MONTH(@date)
     = MONTH(GETDATE()) AND DAY(@date) > DAY(GETDATE())) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Age in Years", 
     (DATEDIFF(MONTH, @date, GETDATE()) - CASE WHEN DAY(@date) > DAY(GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Months", 
     (DATEDIFF(DAY, @date, GETDATE())) AS "DAYS",
     DATEDIFF(Hour,@date,GETDATE()) as [Hour],DATEDIFF(Minute,@date, GETDATE()) as [Minutes],DATEDIFF(Second,@date,GETDATE()) as [Seconds],
    RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @date, 100),2) AS "AM/PM",DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,@date,GETDATE()) as MiliSeconds
```

Comment: Like the error says it overflows. Look up what that means please.

Comment: datepart want only 2 parameter and i'm getting from 2 dates between differences

Comment: OK - think about how big the number of milliseconds is between those two dates. Really big! Too big to store it in the variable.

Comment: so how to store any idea

Comment: or how to store if needed then round the numbers

Comment: Also: the `DATETIME` datatype isn't accurate to the nanoseconds - it's accurate to **3.33ms** only - trying to get nanoseconds from a `DATETIME` is pointless.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to get result in milliseconds for a long period of date and that caused the error.

If the return value is out of range for int (-2,147,483,648 to +2,147,483,647), an error is returned. **For millisecond, the maximum difference between startdate and enddate is 24 days**, 20 hours, 31 minutes and 23.647 seconds. For second, the maximum difference is 68 years.

Source : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms189794.aspx

But, we have a way to get the answer.

```
  1 Sec = 1000 milliseconds. 
  1 Sec = 1000000000 nano seconds.
```

Just convert the result in seconds to decimal and to milliseconds and nano sec.

```
DECLARE @date datetime
    SELECT @date = '2/11/1990 12:03:25.310 AM'
    SELECT (DATEDIFF(yy, @date, GETDATE()) - CASE WHEN (MONTH(@date) > MONTH(GETDATE())) OR (MONTH(@date)
     = MONTH(GETDATE()) AND DAY(@date) > DAY(GETDATE())) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Age in Years", 
     (DATEDIFF(MONTH, @date, GETDATE()) - CASE WHEN DAY(@date) > DAY(GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Months", 
     (DATEDIFF(DAY, @date, GETDATE())) AS "DAYS",
     DATEDIFF(Hour,@date,GETDATE()) as [Hour],DATEDIFF(Minute,@date, GETDATE()) as [Minutes],DATEDIFF(Second,@date,GETDATE()) as [Seconds],
    RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @date, 100),2) AS "AM/PM",

    CAST(DATEDIFF(Second,@date,GETDATE()) AS DECIMAL) * 1000 AS MiliSeconds,
    CAST(DATEDIFF(Second,@date,GETDATE()) AS DECIMAL) * 1000000000 AS NanoSeconds
```